# Flutter ListView.builder not updating after insert

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I've got a SQLite database that I query data from. From such data I create the necessary widgets and store them in a list. Passing the list to ListView.builder I create the items from the list. Everything looks good except when I add new data to the widget list. Nothing shows up if I use `insert`. If I use `add` there's no issue. Here's the snippet.

```
List<MessageItem> _messageItems = <MessageItem>[];


// Reads the data and creates the widgets (all OK here)
// Called when reading the data <<<
_readDBMessages() async {
    List<Map> messages = await readMessages(_threadID);
    List<MessageItem> holderList = <MessageItem>[];
    for (final msg in messages) {
        holderList.add(new MessageItem(
            msg['message'],
            msg['timestamp'],
            msg['status'],
            _contactData['photo']));
    }

    _messageItems.clear();
    setState(() {
        _messages = msges;
        _messageItems = holderList;
    });
}


// When I use _messageItems.add(new MessageItem()); the item shows as expected but it
// it's located on top of the list. Since my ListView is reverse
// I instead use _messagesInsert(0, new MessageItem()); in doing so
// The list is not updated. Scrolling up/down will than proceed to
// show the item as expected.
// Called when storing the data <<<

_storeNewMessage(String message) {
    int timestamp = new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    storeMessage(_threadID, message, _me, 'sending', timestamp, 'text').then((onValue) {
            // _readDBMessages();
            setState(() {
                _messageItems.add(
                    new MessageItem(
                        message, timestamp, 'sending', null
                    )
            );

            print('Message inserted ---------------');
        });
    });
}


// Here's my listView constructor <<<
new Expanded(
    child: new ListView.builder(
        reverse: true,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
        itemCount: (_messageItems == null) ? 0 : _messageItems.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) => _messageItems[i]
    )
),
```

According to Flutter doctor everything is OK, Thanks for the help ;-)

Comment: What is `_messagesInsert(0, new MessageItem)`? Should it be `_messagItems(0, new MessageItem());`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, that was a lazy typo in my comment. I am indeed doing what you suggested.

Comment: Can't imagine why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Perhaps you should pass a unique key to your `MessageItem`.
When you receive a data:

```
new MessageItem(
            msg['message'],
            msg['timestamp'],
            msg['status'],
            _contactData['photo'],
            key: Key(msg['message']+msg['timestamp'].toString())
            )
```

When you add a new entry:

```
        _messageItems.add(
            new MessageItem(
                message, timestamp, 'sending', null, key: Key("${message}${timestamp}")
            )
    );
```

In `MessageItem` constructor:

```
MessageItem(..., {Key key}): super(key: key);
```

---

**Another way** is to specify a random key for the list, something like this:

```
  child: new ListView.builder(
    key: new Key(randomString()),
```

You can read about the keys in https://flutter.io/widgets-intro/#keys or check `Dismissible` widget as an example

Comment: Thanks, I will see if this works. I didn't post the whole code just cause it was a bit long ;)

Comment: Having some issues with this, I'm going to update the question to show what's happpening.

Comment: Adding the key did fix the issue. I just didn't realized I had to cast the value into a Key object (duh!). Thanks for the help! ;)

Comment: Oh, I will fix it in my answer :)

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaah, this works, thanks a lot. I spent a few days trying to understand why the list is updating, but not the view; passing a unique key works great. again thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a ton!  I too wasted hours before I found this.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar problem where I was listening to Floor db changes with StreamBuilder, in which the StreamBuilder was reacting but ListView was not getting updated. Tried the above solution

```
child: new ListView.builder(
key: UniqueKey(),
```

The ListView was then getting updated with new data but there was one problem, in the above implementation the ListView gets refreshed which works great with new data additions, but when I update a data in db or remove a data using dismissible widget, the ListView is again refreshed and the first element is displayed.

So I tried adding the key to each widget in the itemBuilder and it worked for me

```
ListView.builder(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: array.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return ListItemWidget(
          dao: dao,
          item: array[index],
          key: UniqueKey(),
        );
      },
    );
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Amal Paul, just wasted like 3h because of this bug, adding key: UniqueKey() fixed it and forced the ListView.Builder to rebuild the UI.